# Parse XSD Multiple Schema Locations Using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I have gone through several threads on how to read XSD. But I was unable to get a proper answer for it.

So here's my question. I have **XSD** file which has **include element**. So its using **multiple schema** location. I want to read that file in php to get all required elements to create a xml from it. So my first step was on how I should read the XSD file to get all elements to **create a xml file.**

**In Short what I want to do.**

- Read XSD to get all required elements to form xml
- fill xml with my data
- save xml

**What I want to know**

- Can Core PHP do this?
- Is there any ready mate script to do this?
- Should I create a custom method to do this?

**What I tried**

I tried DOMDOCUMENT to load xsd and read file but it does not include multiple schema location files.

Here is my sample xsd File

Main File **Test.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://w3school.com/"
  targetNamespace="http://w3school.com/"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  version="2.1">

  <xsd:include schemaLocation="Headers.xsd"/>

  <xsd:element name="head">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Headers" type="Headers">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
              header
            </xsd:documentation>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Included File **Header.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://w3school.com/"
  targetNamespace="http://w3school.com/"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  version="2.1">


  <xsd:element name="Headers" type="Headers"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="Headers">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="version" minOccurs="1" default="1.0">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>
            This indicates schema version associated with the XML
          </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="1.0" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="0.10.8" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="0.6" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="0.1" />
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="requestId" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>
            request id
          </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

**Expected OutPut**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<head>
    <Headers>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <requestId></requestId>
    </Headers>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I extended a bit the DOMDocument class, in order to handle includes, recursively. See if it helps (further testing needed!)

```
class MyDomDoc extends DOMDocument
{
    public function load($filename, $resolveIncludes = true, $options = null)
    {
        chdir(dirname($filename));

        parent::load($filename, $options);

        if ($resolveIncludes) {
            $this->resolveIncludes();
        }
    }

    public function resolveIncludes()
    {
        $this->resolveNodeIncludes($this);
    }

    private function resolveNodeIncludes(DOMNode $node)
    {
        if ($this->isIncludeNode($node)) {
            $included = new static();
            $included->load($node->attributes->getNamedItem('schemaLocation')->textContent);
            $this->replaceIncludedElements($included, $node);
        }
        elseif ($node->childNodes) {
            foreach ($node->childNodes as $node) {
                $this->resolveNodeIncludes($node);
            }
        }
    }

    private function replaceIncludedElements(DOMDocument $included, DOMNode $replace)
    {
        foreach ($included->firstChild->childNodes as $childNode) {
            $replace->parentNode->insertBefore($this->importNode($childNode, true), $replace);
        }

        $replace->parentNode->removeChild($replace);
    }

    private function isIncludeNode(DOMNode $node)
    {
        return $node->localName == 'include' && $node->namespaceURI == 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$x = new MyDomDoc();
$x->load('path/to/Test.xsd');
echo $x->saveXML();
```

---

#### Update:

Ok, it seems clear from your comment that you don't want to "parse" XSD files (multiple schema locations or otherwise), but rather generate a sample XML that adjusts to a given schema. I think you can use the code in my answer to get a single XSD from multiple locations, and then use that on some tool that generates sample XMLs. Maybe [this](http://xsd2xml.com/) or [this PHP library](https://github.com/goetas-webservices/xsd2php) (I haven't used these tools.)

Comment: tnx mate for your response but this returns me the same xsd file But I want the XML Version of it

Comment: Ohk... So this process will be slight long. Moreover I am generating it run time so probably I need to use the library. I guess there is no ready made library to convert it ?right ?

Comment: @userpk I did some search and found the one I linked. I've never used any of them.

Comment: Its is not the perfect answer I was looking for but worth giving you bounty for you efforts tnxs